# How to find point in sphere surface?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

Let $S$ be a sphere with origin at $(0,0,0)$.

Let $P$ be a point in $S$ surface, whose $y$ coordinate is a given $y_0$.

Let $(x_0, 0, z_0)$ be any point of the line from $(0,0,0)$ to the "shadow" of $P$ (projection of $P$ in the plane $y=0$).

How can I find $P$ ?

[image: sphere ilustration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By spherical coordinates, exchanging y and z with respect to the usual convention in the following image

[image]

$$R=y_0 \cos \phi\implies\cos \phi=\frac{R}{y_0}\implies\sin \phi=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos \phi}$$

Note: the sign depends upon the sign of $y_0$

From $x_0$ and $z_0$ we can obtain

- $\cos \theta = \frac{x_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+z_0^2}}$
- $\sin \theta = \frac{z_0}{\sqrt{x_0^2+z_0^2}}$

then we can calculate

- $x=R\sin \phi \cos \theta$
- $z=R\sin \phi \sin \theta$

therefore we can determine $P(x,y_0,z)$.

Comment: is $\phi$ the angle between the orange and green vectors?

Comment: $\phi$ is the angle between y-axis and orange line

Comment: @Daniel I'm not completely sure of what ypu are looking for please ask in case the help does not fulfil your request.

Comment: I'm looking for x and z coordinates of P, $x_0, y_0, z_0$ are given, $y_0$ is already y-coordinate of P, and $x_0, z_0$ are given just to provide some kind of direction

Comment: @Daniel ok now it is clear! I add some detail

Comment: would it be too hard to swap the $y$ and $z$ axis in the image? I'm having some trouble to visualize

Comment: @Daniel Maybe it would be better to change y and z in the problem, is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Let $u = \frac{(x_0,0,z_0)}{\|(x_0,0,z_0)\|}$. Then, $\langle u, P\rangle = (p_1, 0, p_3)$ where $p_1$ is the x-coordinate of $P$ and $p_3$ is the z-coordinate of $P$. Since you know the $y$ coordinate, we have $P=(p_1, y_0, p_3) = u+(0,y_0,0)$.

Comment: what does $\frac{(x_0,0,z_0)}{||(x_0,0,z_0)||}$ mean? Is it 
$\left( \frac{x_0}{||(x_0,0,z_0)||}, \frac{0}{||(x_0,0,z_0)||}, \frac{z_0}{||(x_0,0,z_0)||} \right) \;$?

Comment: if $u$ is normalized, it will have a magnitude of $1$, which isn't necessarily the length of $P$ projection over plane $y=0$

Comment: Yes, a vector divided by a scalar means to divide each component. $u$ is supposed to be normalized so that the projection $\langle P, U\rangle$ gives exactly the $p_1$ and $p_3$ coordinate of $P$.